# Library Issues when trying to run blender game on different computers

Tags: game-engine, export, blend-files

I've made some games on my home computer (running Ubuntu) using blender (saving it using `bpy.ops.wm.save_as_runtime()`). When I try to run that file on my work computer (running CentOS) i get a load of library errors EG:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've just ran blender from the work computer and saved a game which then runs fine and there's no errors. Is the problem the different OS?

Because I have so many games which are created running various scripts, it's much much easier if I can just use the games created on the home computer (I don't have super user privileges at work).

Are my only two options to either install all the required libraries or create the games on the work computer? Or is there a nicer way of exporting games that will save me?

Comment: I started doing this but there's quite a few and also I got stuck when one of the libraries required `sudo` for the `make install` command

Comment: You could also put all the needed libraries into e.g. a lib folder and then start with LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib/ ./mygame.
You can download e.g. `libpng16` from [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/stable/libpng16-16), select the desired architecture, download the deb packages, extract (don't install) it with an archive manager, and copy the `libpng16.so.16` where you need it. Repeat that for the other dependencies.